# When does SharePoint create the Opened audit event for documents?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am trying to figure out when SharePoint creates the Opened audit event for document. Is it when the binary is downloaded, when the document is locked or when metadata for the document is retrieved etc?

Anyone that knows?

Comment: Which binary are you referring here? If the auditing is specific to opening document then when you open the document in browser or client to read the content, this even is recorded.

Comment: I was thinking about documents specifically, I'm trying to figure out more of the internals of SharePoint on when this is written to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Opened falls under the view type of the audit type enumeration: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms464227(v=office.15)

It is different to check-in/check out. From what I remember viewing encompasses download and opening with client or owa, but not viewing properties (but I am not 100% sure on the last one).

Comment: Thenks, i'm trying to figure out where in the chain of request when a document is opened the actual writing to the database is happening. But i guess it might not be possible to find out.